# Can't access client application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

This application use Identity 4 with client mvc application and IDP(Identity provider) asp.net core web application.

Can't access Controller Index action view.

How to fix this Issue ????

IDP project  Startup project (localhost:44393)

```
 public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                  .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                  .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
                  .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                  .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});
        }
    }
```

Configure.cs file

```
 public static class Config
    {
        public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
        {
            return new List<TestUser>
            {
                new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId ="d866oef",
                    Username ="Kasunjith",
                    Password="password",
                    Claims= new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("given_name","Kasunjith"),
                        new Claim("family_name","Underwood"),
                    }
                }, new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId ="d866omf",
                    Username ="BimalJith",
                    Password="password",
                    Claims= new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("given_name","BimalJith"),
                        new Claim("family_name","ViewWord"),
                    }
                },

            };

        }
        // identity-related resources (Scopes)
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>()
            {
                new Client
                {
                ClientName="Image Galary",
                ClientId="imagegalleryclient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                {
                    "https://localhost:44335/signin-oidc"
                },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId
                },
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                }

                }
            };
        }

    }
```

Client application (localhost:44335)

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            }).AddCookie("Cookies",
           (options) =>
           {

           }).AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
               options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
               options.Authority = "https://localhost:44393";
               options.ClientId = "imagegalleryclient";
               options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
               options.SaveTokens = true;
               options.ClientSecret = "secret";

           });


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Gallery}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

My Controller class

```
 [Authorize]
    public class GalleryController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            await WriteOutIdentityInformation();
            return View();
        }


        public async Task WriteOutIdentityInformation()
        {
            var identityToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken);


            Debug.WriteLine($"Identity token:{identityToken}");

            foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Claim type:{ claim.Type} -Claim value : {claim.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
```

first after login using user name And Password

[image]

After go to localhost:44335/Gallary/index show this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Not 100% sure on this, but</s> I think by default `AddOpenIdConnect` will request `OpenId` and `Profile` scope, however, you've only granted your client `OpenId` scope, so need to add another one.

```
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
            },
```

Comment: I' am new comer in asp .net core identity server 4.how to add new scope to application.and how to configure it??

Comment: @KasunjithBimal This is excerpt from your `Configure.cs`, just add extra line  `IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile` to `AllowedScopes` property.

Comment: I'am add this line to my code. now i show Image Galary is requesting your permission page but not  hit my break point in my controller class.

Comment: @KasunjithBimal Well you need to grant the permission and then it will be redirected back to your app and to your controller.

Comment: @KasunjithBimal You're probably better off asking another question now. This answer has solved your issue in the description. It is hard to understand what problem you are having now without proper context.